# Show Button if GridViewItem is selected

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have WinRT application with following GridView:

```
<GridView x:Name="RouteGrid"
ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRoute,
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
    Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectionMode="Single">         
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="300" Margin="4">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding TermText}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ConnectionObjects.Count}" />
                            </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
             </GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

I want to show a button instead of the second textblock when ever the item is selected because I want to allow my users to navigate to another view when they've selected.

I would like to do it in pure XAML because that is for me the cleanest way but I have no idea how to bind to the IsSelected property of the GridViewItem.

In WPF I would bind the Visibility property of the TextBlock and the button with a BooleanToVisibilityConverter and RelativeSource to the AncestorType GridViewItem and its property but that's not working because WinRT does not know AncestorType :(

Thanks for help.

Comment: So without me having to load up an RT proj, do you have `DataTriggerBehavior` available? If so you should be able to grab the IsSelected bool from the item and use a ChangePropertyAction to toggle the visibility on the button all from within the datatemplate.

Comment: My problem is, that I can't access IsSelected. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: {Binding IsSelected, ElementName=RouteGrid} The ElementName is just to reach outside of the context of the datatemplate, should be all you need.

Comment: That's not working. I need the IsSelected of the corresponding GridViewItem. Because I just want to show the button if the element is selected. With ElementName=RouteGrid, I get the Grid instead of its item.

Comment: Not sure how you're using it, that little example wasn't literal since it's pointing to its parent so was probably easily misinterpreted. The idea would be to set a datatrigger on the item to throw a changepropertyaction at the button inside the same item itemplate.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a @Harald-K. ?